# How to define Pod health check port for livenessProbe/readinessProbe

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-health-check

How do I define distinct Pod ports, one for application and another for health check (readinessProbe)?

Is the specification for ports, shown below, a correct way to make the readinessProbe to check the health check port TCP/9090 ? I mean, is the readinessProbe going to reach port 9090 (assuming it is open by the running container of course) ? Or does one need to specify any other port (nodePort, targetPort, port, whatever) ?

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: <image>
        ports:
        - name: myapp-port
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        - name: healthcheck-port
          containerPort: 9090
          protocol: TCP

        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            port: healthcheck-port
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 2
          failureThreshold: 2
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for different port for health check? We have health check endpoint part of same application port.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your specification snippet is *almost* correct. You don't need to specify any thing else to make readiness probe work.

Port names cannot be more than 15 characters, so the name `healthcheck-port` won't work. You might want to change the name to something smaller like `healthcheck`.

Comment: where did you get that port names can't be longer then 15 characters?

Comment: oh yeah. just made a test. Is it documented?

Comment: It's in the [validation code.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/validation/validation.go#L284)

Comment: [Updated link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.24.0-alpha.0/staging/src/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/validation/validation.go#L330)

Answer (score 2):

Your current configuration is almost correct as mentioned by @shashank-v except the port name.

What i would rather like to point out here apart from the name is to use the same port as best practice, which is TCP/8080 but have a `healthz` path where you application responds with `ok` or `running`. then in your httpget:

```
readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        port: 8080
        path: /healthz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any port and path (assuming it's http) for `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe`, but, of course, you need to be serving something there.

It shouldn't be a service port, so `NodePort` is not an option, as that's `kubelet` in charge of the health of the containers, and it has direct access to the containers.

Answer (score 0):

```
readinessProbe:
  tcpSocket:
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 10
```

Good reference:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-tcp-liveness-probe